# Option selected con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, select, options

Tengo este código, pero no me deja como selected el option que he marcado. Alguien sabe ¿por qué?

```
<select class="choose" [(ngModel)]="selectInfo">
                <option value="" selected >Selecciona Opción</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.nombre">{{item.nombre}}

                </option>
              </select>
```

He probado también con

> selected = true;
>
> [attr.selected]=true

Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como estás usando `ngModel`, puedes asignar el valor por defecto en el componente. Prueba:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectInfo = '';
}
```

y la opción que tenga ese valor (una cadena vacía) será seleccionada.

Lo puedes ver en [este StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjjty1).

Comment: Perfecto. Mil gracias!